# how to read a sqlite3 decimal column?

Tags: sqlite, decimal, currency

I can read a text and an int column (sqlite3_column_text, sqlite3_column_int).
But does anyone know how to read in a sqlite decimal column?

The decimal columns essentially hold currency values.

Thanks!

Comment: I have scoured the internet search engines, as well as iphone forums & sqlite3 documentations, yet still not information on reading decimal values. Surely this can be done... but HOW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this list of functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html). Yours is `sqlite3_column_double`.

Comment: Thanks. So i guess i need to convert the double to a decimal? Also, is Core-Data the prefered way to store data rather using sqlite?